# Can I use hanging indentations for my bibliography references with bibtex?

Tags: bibliographies, indentation

I have used `hangparas` from the hanging package, tried setting `bibhang`, setting `parskip` and `leftindent` to no avail. I have an author-year citation format and `plainnat.bst` and `savetrees` package if this matters...

Most help I find on this topic suggests use of biblatex but as I have not yet made the switch. I still find bibtex's multiple bibliography style option very useful so would like to stay with bibtex for now.

**Edit:** For example, I was hoping this would help, but it does nothing for the bibliography:

```
\begin{hangparas}{.25in}{1}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}
\end{hangparas}
```

I also tried

```
\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}
\leftskip 0.1in
\parindent -0.1in
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}
```

and

```
\setlength\bibhang{2em}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}
```

But there is no hanging indentation to be seen.

Comment: BibTeX has nothing to do with this, but the class and packages you're using do. So a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is needed.

Comment: Do you use a citation management package such as `natbib` or `harvard`? Please advise.

Comment: Yes, I use `natbib` and I've edited my question to say it's the bibliography that I want to indent.

Comment: It would be really nice if you provided a MWE as suggested by @egreg. I think that after asking 16 questions you would understand that this makes the question much better and the answering much easier...

Comment: I also added an example in my last edit.

Comment: @crippledlambda No, that's not an example. An example starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`; a couple of bibliography items from your `.bib` file are also needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had posted a complete minimal example, you probably would've had a solution many hours ago.  And, needless to say, if this solution doesn't work for you, you really need to post a similar example of your own that demonstrates the problem.

At any rate, this works for me:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{example.bib}
@book{smith2000,
  author =    {Smith, John},
  title =     {A Really, Really, Really Long Book Title So the Whole Entry Is More than One Line Long},
  address =   {City},
  publisher = {Some Publisher},
  year =      2000
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{natbib}
% \usepackage[normalbib]{savetrees}% older versions
\usepackage[bibliography=normal]{savetrees}% version 2.0 (2011/05/14)
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\cite{smith2000}
\lipsum[1]

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{example}

\end{document}
```

In other words, `savetrees` allows you to set various options that determine how many trees you're going to save.  In this case, the `bibliography=normal` option prevents `savetrees` from modifying the bibliography formatting.

Comment: Hey thanks, running a tight deadline so haven't gotten a chance to put together an example but `filecontents` is convenient - didn't know. Also, apparently `normalbib` option is deprecated in favor of `bibliography=normal` (http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/savetrees/savetrees.dtx) and then I changed `\setlength\bibsep{0pt}` (as suggested here: http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/squeeze.html) since I'm using natbib. Greatly appreciate you pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @crippledlambda -- thanks.  I updated my answer (and my version of `savetrees`).  I'm not sure why you need the `\setlength` command though: it won't make any difference in the example I posted.  Though perhaps you are using other `savetrees` options or other packages that are interfering with your `\bibsep` settings....

Comment: Thanks, @jon. That may be the case. At some point I will have to go through my (long) preamble to see what is causing a change in `\bibsep`. I'll report back if I figure this out...